# Unexpected string in JSON at position 608 while parsing

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I'm trying to host my react website to GitHub, but when I try to use:

```
npm install --save gh-pages
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 608 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "myportfoliosite",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "versio'
```

The repository is at: https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/React-Developer-Portfolio2

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myportfoliosite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/React-Developer-Portfolio2",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to follow the instructions under the GitHub pages folder at:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

But I am stuck, can someone please check what's wrong with the file?

Comment: It tells you where the error is, and what the error is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This package.json was not a valid JSON you can try to fix the JSON structure, using online tools like and  validate the JSON

https://jsoneditoronline.org/

https://jsonformatter.org/

below JSON should work for you:

```
    {
      "name": "myportfoliosite",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/React-Developer-Portfolio2",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue and my json was valid and structured.
This issue was due to invalid package-lock.json file. Delete your `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install`. It will re-generate your package-lock.json file and works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason can be your package-lock.json file. Sometimes it gets corrupted, so you have to delete that file and run the npm install again.

Answer (score 3):

Your `package.json` file is malformed, I ran into the same issues locally. I fixed them like so, please note the `<-` comments indicating what I changed.

```
{
  "name": "myportfoliosite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/React-Developer-Portfolio2",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject" <- Removed an extra comma here
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  } <- Removed an extra comma here
} <- You missed a final closing curly bracket here
```

With the changes I had no problem installing `gh-pages`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I implemented your changes and got the following error:  Unexpected string in JSON at position 613 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "myportfoliosite",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "versio'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it could be an error in the declaration of the json object,  check double quotes, commas, brackets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that it happens related to "gh-pages"
for me as well....that is a common denominator for ending up here.  I have one clue.. I edited by hand adding the 'homepage' field instructed by the gh-pages tutorial and it did not show a comma at the end of the line. And my mind was enough asleep to not realize one was needed. Goes for the other of those lines as well. Remember also last line of a section shall not end with a comma. So if you insert your line as the last line of a section (thus not with a comma) remember the previous last line now needs a comma.

See https://terieyenike.medium.com/how-to-deploy-react-apps-to-github-16830823a9fa  Step 3..

The error message telling what character position in the file lead me to it.