# Unexpected string in JSON at position 41

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I'm a newbie to Javascript, I do not quite know what this error means:

```
SyntaxError: /home/runner/myrepl/config.json:
Unexpected string in JSON at position 41
```

My index.js looks fine at position 41 (I think).

Here is my config.json if that helps:

```
{
  "DISCORD_ID": "mydiscordIDishere"
  "CMDS": "mycommandschannelIDishere"
}
```

I have, discord.js, discord, npm and node.js installed. Please help I feel like I am really close to complete this project.

I am trying to make it work through discord by easy commands like p!pois uaid.
Though I have spent quite a while trying to fix problems like these and I don't quite get how to solve it. I am running this on Replit.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"DISCORD_ID": "mydiscordIDishere"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected string in JSON at position 608 while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813744/unexpected-string-in-json-at-position-608-while-parsing)

Comment: Yes Thank you so much!!!!!! Now I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/myrepl/index.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to just add a comma on the 2nd line of config.json
Actually:

```js
{
  "DISCORD_ID": "mydiscordIDishere"
  "CMDS": "mycommandschannelIDishere"
}
```

**After:**

```
{
  "DISCORD_ID": "mydiscordIDishere",
  "CMDS": "mycommandschannelIDishere"
}
```